# How to resolve Struts 2 Json Interceptor invalid json exception

Tags: json, struts2

Hi i upgraded my struts project from 2.3.20 to 2.5.2 and when i am trying to run, it is throwing me exception in JsonInterceptor. I am unable to figure out why it throwing this exception after upgrading struts to 2.5.2. I have also change my struts.xml file according to it. But still it is showing me same error. Can anyone help me what i am missing.

Error Trace:
[image]

struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="json-default,struts-default"> 
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="sessionInterceptor" class="com.comviva.mconnectui.custom.interceptors.SampleInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="customInterceptor">
                <interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-ref name="json" /> 
            </interceptor-stack> 
         </interceptors>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Please post text as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: Is it working in the old version?

Comment: yes it is working with the old version of struts

Comment: @Paresh In the old version did you use the same `struts.xml`?

Comment: yes i have use the struts.xml with my old version also